# How to analyse .so file? [Android/Linux]

Tags: android, linux, shared-libraries, openmax

everyone.

I need to analyse the libOMXAL.so of Android. (That one is in the NDK folder)

// I need to find out whether this file contains the Implementation of OMXCLient.cpp or not.

I want to analyse this .so file to find out which function it contains. My OS is Windows7.

I am new on this. Could anyone give me a hint? Thank you!

Comment: Did you figure it out?  I'm curious.  Did you have access to **OMXClient.cpp** source code.

Answer (score 3):

You can try "nm -D -l libOMXAL.so" under linux to find the symbols in libOMXAL.so.

Maybe you will also can get the source files contain the OMXClient.cpp or not.

Answer (score 2):

If it's only the .so file then try to call any methods in the lib belong to "OMXClient.cpp". If there is any error, probably the .so doesn't contain the "OMXClient.cpp". If you have the source files, checkout the "jni" folder in the project, in file "Android.mk", see if the "OMXClient.cpp" is one of the files compiling in this line "LOCAL_SRC_FILES := OMXClient.cpp". Hope this helps.

Comment: And you could also run `nm -D -C libOMXAL.so` to find out what is defined inside that library...

Comment: It really helps. Thanks. I want to analyse this .so file to find out which function it contains. Do you have any solution for this? Thank you!

Comment: I recommend you to copy this file to any linux/unix based system , and them you can run following commands to find outlines of what this file is using ,
nm -D -C libOMXAL.so

also

strings libOMXAL.so
will give you additional information ...